# existe algo parecido a os.getcwd() para socket?

Tags: python, socket

Cuando me conecto servidor-cliente, al ejecutar el cliente, me informa de la ip del equipo en el que estoy conectado y su nombre, también me gustaría que me informará de la carpeta actual en el que estoy trabajando, y para ello, me preguntaba, si exista una funcion socket que me proporcione cuya información. Como por ejemplo existe `socket.gethostname()'.

```
name_host_server = socket.gethostname()
carpeta_actual_server =  #<-- ?
while True:
   mens = raw_input("\033[1;31m"+host+"\033[1;32m"+"@"+name_host_server+":"+"\033[1;34m"+carpeta_actual_server+"\033[0;37m"+"$ ")
   if mens == "close":
      os.system("fuser -k -n tcp %s" % port)
      break
   #Con el metodo send, enviamos el mensaje
   obj.send(mens)
   data = obj.recv(1073741824)
   if data.count("descarga -f"):
      ruta = input("ruta absoluta, donde se descargará el archivo >>")
      archivo_filtro = data.replace("descarga -f |","")
      lista_archivo = archivo_filtro.split("|")
      nombre_archivo = lista_archivo[0]
      restante = nombre_archivo+"|"
      archivo_filtro2 = archivo_filtro.replace(restante,"")
      crear_ruta = ruta+nombre_archivo
      archivo_descargar = open(crear_ruta,"a")
      archivo_descargar.write(archivo_filtro2)
      archivo_descargar.close()
      print("\033[0;32m"+"[+]"+"\033[0;37m"+"archivo descargado correctamente")
  else:
      print(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso deberías implementarlo en el cliente. Es decir, tú deberías mandar un mensaje al cliente diciéndole "quiero tu directorio actual" y en el cliente deberías hacer que si el mensaje recibido es "quiero tu directorio actual" devuelva la ejecución de "os.getcwd()". De hecho, socket.gethostname() lo único que hace es devolverte el hostname del equipo en el cual está ejecutándose ese código, nunca te devolverá el hostname de un equipo remoto.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.gethostname